# Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1, payment-methods, fatal-error

any help identifying the error will be highly appreciated.

on magento admin I getting the following error message when trying to access the payment methods. `"Fatal error: Call to a member function isSandbox() on a non-object in Block/System/Config/Forms/Checkbox.php on line 13"`

Here is the code for `Checkbox.php`:

```
class Paguelofacil_Pagocash_Block_System_Config_Forms_Checkbox extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $cvalue = Mage::getModel('Gateway/Config_Settings')->isSandbox();
        $checkActive = (Mage::getModel('Gateway/Config_Settings')->isSandbox()==1)?'checked':'';
        $html = "
        <input type='hidden' value='".$cvalue."' id='payment_Pagocash_sandbox' name='groups[Gateway][fields][sandbox][value]'>
       <input type='checkbox' class='select' onclick='pagueloFacilChange(this)' ".$checkActive."> Habilitado PagoCash Sandbox
       <script type='text/javascript'>
            function pfpagoCashChange(currentElement)
            {
                document.getElementById('payment_Pagocash_sandbox').value = (currentElement.checked)?1:0;
            }
       </script>
       ";
        //}

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: This model `Mage::getModel('Gateway/Config_Settings')` is not part of magento core. Please post config.xml of the related module.

Answer (score 1):

The method `Mage::getModel('Gateway/Config_Settings')` is returning `null`, meaning that Magento cannot resolve `Gateway/Config_Settings` to a Magento model.

Now it's been a while since I've worked with Magento 1, but my best guess is that your configuration path is incorrect (don't know if it's case-sensitive, so you could try `gateway/config_settings`, or that there is no such class in the module that is providing the `gateway`-namespace (typical path should be `Vendor/Module/Model/Config/Settings.php`).